# How to change the values of boolean fields in ElasticSearch by Python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, boolean

I use elasticsearch package in Python to transfer data between two different elasticsearch environments. To modify the values (such as 0, 1, '0', and '1') of boolean fields to boolean values (true and false), I use the following script:

```
for k, v in res['_source'].iteritems():

     if (k in boolean_fields) and (not isinstance(res['_source'][k], bool)):

         if res['_source'][k] in ['1', 1]:
            res_no_empty['_source'][k] = 'true'

         elif res['_source'][k] in ['0', 0]:
            res_no_empty['_source'][k] = 'false' 

response_list.append(res_no_empty)
bulk(es_destination, response_list, chunk_size=1000)
```

Then error will arise because the mapping of these fields are boolean but the values is string.

I also tried the following script (replaced 'true' with True and 'false' with False):

```
 if (k in boolean_fields) and (not isinstance(res['_source'][k], bool)):

     if res['_source'][k] in ['1', 1]:
        res_no_empty['_source'][k] = True

     elif res['_source'][k] in ['0', 0]:
        res_no_empty['_source'][k] = False
```

but in elasticsearch environment, nothing is showed for boolean fields that had values in ['0', 0, '1', 1]; however if the original field has a *true/false* value, the elasticsearch shows the correct values.

Comment: Elasticsearch handles types via [mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html). Have you adjusted mappings to have bool type?

Comment: Yes, I defined the mapping as boolean.